# Maven Error - could not resolve dependencies for project

Tags: maven

I am following the steps given at

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#java

When I run 'mvn clean install' , I get following error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project MySel20Proj: Could not resolve dependencies for project MySel20Proj:MySel20Proj:jar:1.0: Failed to collect dependencies for [org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:2.28.0 (compile), com.opera:operadriver:jar:1.1 (compile)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.webbitserver:webbit:jar:0.4.14: Could not transfer artifact org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent:pom:6 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Read timed out -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Check this [Opera driver](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opera/operadriver/0.7.3). This driver is not default part of Selenium because it's developed by 3rd party. Look at this [page](http://seleniumhq.org/download/), if you scroll down little bit, there is a list with 3rd party drivers with links to them.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that the Support for Opera in Selenium 2.28 is not present till date... Please correct me If I am wrong

Comment: More over you can check this link also for more info...  http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/OperaDriver

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a network issue , I tried again and it was successful !
Thanks anyways for your help.